# Pre-populated Realm isn't being copied on the first launch

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, realm

I populated .realm file elsewhere & now I want to use it as a database. To make this story shorter, let's just assume I've followed [the manual](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#bundling-a-realm-with-an-app) exactly, except for its' last part, which is, well, treatable.

The problem is when I first launch the app, the .realm file isn't being copied, however after I relaunch the app (in simulator / on a real device), it works well.

I tried referencing [the migration sample](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/tree/master/examples/ios/swift-2.1.1/Migration), and, to be honest, it just confused me more and that is evidently why I'm here seeking help.

Here's where I'm wrong:

```
import RealmSwift

func bundlePath(path: String) -> String? {
    let resourcePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath as NSString?
    return resourcePath?.stringByAppendingPathComponent(path)
}
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func openRealm() {
        let defaultPath = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.path!
        if let v0Path = bundlePath("names.realm") {
            do {
                try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(defaultPath)
                try NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(v0Path, toPath: defaultPath)
                print("Copied.")
            } catch {
            print("Wasn't copied.")
            }
        }
    }
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

openRealm()

let realm = try! Realm()
print("NamesCount: \(realm.objects(Names).count)")

return true
}
```

Thank you for your time & for reading this, now please help me out. Why am I seeing

> Wasn't copied.
>   NamesCount: 0

on first launch and

> Copied.
>   NamesCount: 7

on second launch and on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an issue in another place ;)

The first `try` trowing an exception at first run because you don't have this file yet. And `copyItemAtPath` not calling after that. So you have an empty default realm file with no data after all of this.

```
func openRealm() {
    let defaultPath = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.path!
    if let v0Path = bundlePath("names.realm") {
        if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(defaultPath) {
            do {
                try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(defaultPath)
                print("Remove old file")
            } catch {
                print("Wasn't removed")
            }
        }
        do {
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(v0Path, toPath: defaultPath)
            print("Copied.")
        } catch {
            print("Wasn't copied.")
        }
    }
}
```